# How to lower security level of IE on Win 2008R2 to allow product register?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer

There is IE 11 installed on Win2008R2 server. After installing a Visual studio express, we are asked to register the software. A user account was created on outlook.com. However after entering login info on live.com when following the registering instruction, the browser comes out with blank page and hangs. We figure that it may be the security level of IE is set to HIGH. But there is only one level of security available which is HIGH for internet zone. What's the right way to reduce the IE security level on 2008 R2 server so we can use it to register?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try adding the website as a trusted site. By white listing certain sites, security settings are reduced when visiting them. Depending on how many "sites" a webpage tries to access, you may need to do this several times.

```
Open Internet Explorer by clicking the Start button . In the search box, type Internet Explorer, and then, in the list of results, click Internet Explorer.

Click the Tools button, and then click Internet options.
Click the Security tab.
Now click on Trusted sites and then click on the sites button.
Enter the Website URL and click on Add.
When you are finished, click on Close.
```